# How to store a png from Matplotlib figure in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gif

I have a code that creates 20 images that I want to save as a GIF. Instead of saving each image individually and then reloading them into the program to make a GIF out of them, I want the png versions of the axis to be stored in a list, so that I can skip the saving and reloading part.

Here is the way I currently do it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import imageio

def make_gif(gif_direc, video_frames):
    fig1 = plt.Figure()
    axes = fig1.add_subplot()

    for j in range(20):
        axes.clear()
        # Here I would plot all the stuff onto the axis.
        fig1.savefig(gif_direc + "Frame_" + str(j + 1) + ".png", format="png")

    images = []
    for j in range(20):
        images.append(imageio.imread(gif_direc + "Frame_" + str(j + 1) + ".png"))

    # Now the GIF is saved.
    imageio.mimsave(gif_direc + "Particle Impact.gif", images, duration=0.25)
```

Comment: you could use a [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) as nicely shown here: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/drawing-animated-gifs-with-matplotlib/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I don't want to have ax as a global variable, how could I pass it to the update method that was described in the blog?

Comment: if you define your update method within your `make_gif` function it'll have access to your `axes` variable